# MKAnnotationView shows callout before dragging pin

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotationview

I have a set of `MKPinAnnotationView`s that are draggable and can show callouts. When I want to drag a pin by longpressing the pin, its callout opens and disables my touch so I have longpress AGAIN to start dragging. I don't want this behaviour and prefer dragging the pin on first touch. Is there a way to control this behaviour? Or is there a way to show callouts on `Touch Up Inside` instead of `Touch Down`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer myself:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    [view setSelected:YES];
}
```

Comment: I am stuck with the same behavior of MKPinAnnotationView. It is not working in iOS 9.0. The above delegate method is never called.